# Microsoft Teams Camera Preview Add-in

Tags: windows, add-in, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create a simple add-in to insert a picture from camera, as a messaging extension. I need to display a video preview to make it work. The wording is confusing, "implemented by the Bot Framework, but are NOT supported by Teams".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#cards-not-supported-in-teams

Is it possible to implement a video preview, through an add-in?

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a video/video preview is not currently supported in Teams. You could try using [TaskModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules) to display the video inside teams.